# How to check Win API function support during runtime?

Tags: c++, windows, api

How can I check during runtime whether the function `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` is supported by the runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the famous [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to lookup the function's existence, like this

```
typedef void (WINAPI *FuncT) (LPFILETIME lpSystemTimeAsFileTime);

HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"Kernel32.dll");
FuncT GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime = (FuncT) GetProcAddress((HMODULE)hDLL, L"GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime");

if (GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime)
{
   // function is exposed by the DLL, now it can be called
   GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(...);
}
```

Comment: I had to move the WINAPI call signature inside the parenthesis (WINAPI *FuncT) to make VS12 happy.